# How to open up browser after login with MechanicalSoup and Python script?

Tags: python, browser, mechanicalsoup

I write a Python script with the help of `MechanicalSoup` to automate a login task.
The script successfully runs and I can see that `get_url()` method returns a `url` which tells login is successful.
At the end, I want to open up a browser (Google Chrome in my case) at the page after login happened but the problem is that I need again enter username and password via Chrome itself!

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should use selenium
Forexample for login instagram by firefox the python code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
#######################################################################################
emailOrPhone=driver.find_element_by_name("emailOrPhone")
fullName = driver.find_element_by_name("fullName")
username=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy       "]')
#######################################################################################
emailOrPhone.send_keys('somayeteymuri721373@gmail.com')
fullName.send_keys("somayeteymuri")
username.send_keys("yusf4ty72")
password.send_keys("1752s1353")
login_btn.click()
########################################################################################
```

Comment: Really thank dear @yasin for the great help.
The only problem that I currently have is I want to first run this code in headless mode and then after login happens I open up browser and show the page behind login stage.
I searched a lot about this with no luck!
Is it possible with selenium?

Comment: You mean try login and after the successful login the webpage load?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but notice that after successful login browser should open up and then load the webpage.

Comment: do you want hack sth?

Comment: No, I just want to not show the user what is happening except the final page.

Comment: you should send tcp request. you should know html very well  and one programing language

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this >>

```
import mechanicalsoup as mch

browser = mch.StatefulBrowser()

## your code here to login to website

browser.launch_browser()
```